# Stacked table spreading and merging

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, tidyr

I download SKOS Schema table from W3C to prepare a Vocabulary mapping mission. This is an example build in “dput”:

```
> dput(skosc)
structure(list(X1 = c("skos:Collection", "URI:", "Definition:", 
"Label:", "Disjoint classes:", "skos:Concept", "URI:", "Definition:", 
"Label:", "Disjoint classes:", "skos:ConceptScheme", "URI:", 
"Definition:", "Label:", "Disjoint classes:", "skos:OrderedCollection", 
"URI:", "Definition:", "Label:", "Super-classes:"), X2 = c("skos:Collection", 
"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Collection", "Section 9. \r\n      Concept Collections", 
"Collection", "skos:Conceptskos:ConceptScheme", "skos:Concept", 
"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept", "Section 3. The \r\n      skos:Concept Class", 
"Concept", "skos:Collectionskos:ConceptScheme", "skos:ConceptScheme", 
"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#ConceptScheme", "Section 4. \r\n      Concept Schemes", 
"Concept Scheme", "skos:Collectionskos:Concept", "skos:OrderedCollection", 
"http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#OrderedCollection", "Section 9. \r\n      Concept Collections", 
"Ordered Collection", "skos:Collection")), .Names = c("X1", "X2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

There is an odd in this stacked table besides the subtitle of each small table(such as “skos:Collection”, “skos:Concept” and so on) which we must notice: the rownames are not all the same either, like No. 20 Row in the example, it names “Super-classes:”, not “Disjoint classes:” as above small tables.
My plan is split this stacked table and transposition it as follows:

Before:

[image: the origin table before we process]

After:

[image: the table after processing should be]

“dplyr” and “tidyr” are both good at manipulating tables, and I choose “spread” function which can change table from long and narrow to short and wide. Unfortunately, it failed:

```
> skosns<-"http://www.w3.org/2009/08/skos-reference/skos.html"
> require(rvest)
载入需要的程辑包：rvest
载入需要的程辑包：xml2
> skospg<-read_html(skosns, encoding = "UTF-8", options = c("RECOVER", "NOERROR", "NSCLEAN"))
> skosnd<-html_nodes(skospg, "table")
> skosc<-html_table(skosnd[[1]], header = FALSE, trim = TRUE, fill = FALSE, dec = ".")
> skosp<-html_table(skosnd[[2]], header = FALSE, trim = TRUE, fill = FALSE, dec = ".")
> require(tidyr)
载入需要的程辑包：tidyr
> spread(skosc, key = X1, value = X2)
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (3, 8, 13, 18), (5, 10, 15), (4, 9, 14, 19), (2, 7, 12, 17)
```

The error massage didn’t tell me much about the reason, but I guess it maybe the odd row leads to this error. Can we ignore the differences among small tables and only spread the same value into different columns?

- Question Updated:

The code post by scholar akrun in the commont is very helpful, I learned if there are 2 more values in one column, we need to group them and mutate the structure first. Then the data frame can be spread. Thanks to akrum!!!
Now comes the last process: delete there column of vocabulary name(such as "skos:Collection") and transfer them to the corresponding rows. But I have a weak point on write built-in function, so the program failed unsurprisingly:

```
> require(rvest)
> skospg<-read_html(skosns, encoding = "UTF-8", options = c("RECOVER", "NOERROR", "NSCLEAN"))
> skosnd<-html_nodes(skospg, "table")
> skosc<-html_table(skosnd[[1]], header = FALSE, trim = TRUE, fill = FALSE, dec = ".")
> require(dplyr)
> skosc_g<-group_by(skosc, X1)
> skosc_m<-mutate(skosc_g, n = row_number())
> require(tidyr)
载入需要的程辑包：tidyr
> skosc_t<-spread(skosc_m, key = X1, value = X2)
> vocn<-select_all(skosc_t, funs(colnames=grep("[[:alpha:]]+:[[:alpha:]]+")))
Error in grep("[[:alpha:]]+:[[:alpha:]]+") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
> merge.data.frame(vocn, skosc_t, by=c("Collection", "Concept", "ConceptScheme"))
Error in as.data.frame(x) : object 'vocn' not found
```

The plan of this paragraph is to extract the columns which have a value as those vocabulary names{skosc_t[c(5,6,7,8),]}, then merge them with the dataframe in which these columns has been deleted{skosc_t[c(2,3,4,9,10),]}:
[image: whole skosc_t dataframe]
What to do is correct? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Because there is duplicate elements, you need to create a sequence column i.e. `skosc %>% group_by(X1) %>% mutate(n = row_number()) %>% spread(X1, X2)`

Comment: Before I post this question here, I have tried “group” functions, they can get all the rows which have same values together. But I’m not sure what does “mutate” do here. And when I tried to rewrite the program post by akrun into classic style, I encounter another error:
`> require(dplyr)
载入需要的程辑包：dplyr
> skosc_g<-group_by(skosc, X1)
> skosc_m<-mutate(n = row_number(skosc_g))
Error: Can't use matrix or array for column indexing
> require(tidyr)
载入需要的程辑包：tidyr
> spread(skosc_m, key = X1, value = X2)
Error in spread(skosc_m, key = X1, value = X2) : 
  object 'skosc_m' not found`

Comment: My code was `row_number()` and not `row_number(skosc_g)`